# Is the following function bijective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is this function bijective? Bijective means both onto and 1 to 1

$$
F(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}
$$

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Edit: The domain is ${\rm I\!R}$

Comment: What is its domain?

Comment: Are we to assume that $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$? Further, you could try sketching the graph to give you _some_ idea.

Comment: To visualize the curve, it may be helpful to rewrite our expression as $1-\frac{1}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: It is an even function.  It cannot be injective unless you are pruning its natural domain.

Comment: The domain is real numbers, sorry, I forgot to add that. I'll edit it.

Comment: It should be immediately apparent that f (-x)=f(x) so it can't be 1-1.  It should also be apparent f (x)>0 so it isn't onto R.  Not so apparent but still clear f(x) < 1 so it's *really* not onto 1.  But *maybe* it's a bijection from [0,inf) to [1/2,1).  In fact, I'm pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $F\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as in @probablyme's comment.

**Hint:** draw a picture of the graph of the function. Can you find a horizontal line that intersects two points on the graph? If so, what can you say about the 1-to-1 property?

**Alternative hint:** does the function ever output negative numbers? If so, what can you say about the onto property?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ is squared in all places where it occurs, the value of the function is always positive.  So the function is not onto $\mathbb{R}$ and hence not bijective.

Answer (score 1):

The function $F$:$ \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not a bijective function.

Because when $F(1)= 2/3, F(-1) = 2/3$, that invalidate the [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection). (i.e. if $ F(x) = F(y)$, $x$ equals to $y$)  which shows that it is not a bijective function.

As par said, F(x) is not subjective on $\mathbb{R}$,for the range of F is the subset of $[0,+ \infty )$

However the function $F$:$ \mathbb{[0,+\infty) }\rightarrow [0.5,1 )$
by checking the monotony and symmetry of function $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let f be a function from R+.Every function is onto. To show 1-1: Assume (x^2+1)/(x^2+2) =(y^2+1)/(y^2+2) . If x^2+1=y^2+1, x=y and we are done. Similarly if x^2+2=y^2+2. Assume x^2+1=alpha(y^2+1). Then necessarily x^2+2=alpha(y^2+2). But this is impossible.

Comment: What do you mean every function is onto.  If y =1, f (x) =1 is impossible.  It's not onto.  I don't understand the second half.  Do you think you are proving it is 1-1 or not one-to-one one?

Comment: Every function is onto its range. It doesn't matter what I think i am proving.  What did I prove? I assumed f(x)=f(y) and then if the numerator of f(x) is the numerator of f(y) then x=y, if the denominator of f(x) is the denominator of f(y) then x=y. Moreover they cannot be eual without eual numerator (with numerator and denominator being the obvious numerator and denominator shown in the problem)

Comment: Every function is onto its *range* but the range is not specified being onto refers to being onto the specified or implied codomain (otherwise the term is trivial). This function is onto [1/2, 1) but it is not onto R. It is not an onto real function because its image it not the real numbers. The stated domain was R, not R+.  So if $x \ne - x; f(x) \ne f(-x)$.  So it is neither 1-1 from R nor onto R so f:R->R is not a bijection but f:R+->image(f(R+)) is. (Actually f:R+U{0}->[1/2,1) is bijection.)  I found it hard to follow your 1-1 argument and I was't sure if you were arguing it was or wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not a bijection as it is neither 1-1 nor onto.

However, $f:[0, \infty)\rightarrow [\frac 12,1) $ **IS** a bijection.  Which only goes to show, that when you make a claim such as "f is bijection" it is essential you specify on what domain and range you are referring.

Claim 1:  $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not 1-1.

Pf. Let $x\ne 0$.  Then $x \ne -x$.  But $x^2 = (-x)^2$ so $f(-x)=f (x)$.

Claim 2: $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not onto.

Pf: $x^2 + 1 > 0$ and $x^2 + 2 > 0$ so $f(x) >0$ so for any $y \le 0$ there are no $x$ so that $f(x) = y$.

Furthermore $x^2 + 2 > x^2 + 1$ so $f(x) < 1$ so for any $y \ge 1$ there are no $x$ so that $f(x) =y$.

Claim 3: $f: [0,x)\rightarrow [1/2,1)$ is 1-1.

Pf.
If $f(x) = f(y)$ then $\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 2} = \frac{y^2 + 1}{y^2 + 2}$.

So $(x^2 + 1)(y^2 + 2)=(x^2 +2)(y^2 + 1)$ so

$x^2y^2 + y^2 + 2x^2 + 2 = x^2y^2 + x^2 + 2y^2 + 2$  so

$x^2 = y^2$ so $\pm x = \pm y$.  But as $x$ and $y$ are both in $[0,\infty)$ they are both non negative.  So $x = y$.  So is 1-1.

Claim 4:  $f: [0,x)\rightarrow [1/2,1)$ is onto.

$f$ is clearly continuous.  And $\lim_x\rightarrow \infty f(x) = 1$ clearly.  $f(0) = 1/2$.  So for all $y \in [1/2,1)$ the exists an $x \in [0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)$ by intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Actually if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is not onto you can always find a range that it **is** onto by restricting to the image.  $f:X \rightarrow Image(f(X)) \subset Y$ will *always* be onto.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph of $f$.

[image: Graph of F]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMCyo.png))

**Injectivity:** $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$

This property is given, if every function value is not assigned to more than one ordinate $x$.

Which is not the case here, the graph of $F$ is symmetric to the $y$-axis, and for $x \ne 0$ we have $f(x) = f(-x)$.

**Surjectivity:** Every point of the codomain has a function value assigned.

The codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ (as nothing specific is said) and e.g. $y = 0$ is not in the image of $F$.